# Capturing High Sample Rate I2S via USB

Tags: usb, audio, adc, i2s

Recently, I started working on a project to convert my Sony XDR-F1HD radio to a device that I can connect to over ideally USB to record the RF signal off of the air. All demodulation and processing is done with DSP, so the RF signal's baseband is digitized using an ADC. The ADC on these units is incredibly good, making them one of the best consumer radios ever sold.

The digitized baseband signal out of the ADC is available on the board as four lines carrying an I²S signal: two data lines, a clock, and the word select line. It should be easy enough to tap onto these lines and attach something to process the I2S protocol, however the sample rate of this is much higher than your typical I2S signal. Here are my measurements for the two clocks:

- Word Select: 325 kHz
- Bit Clock: 10.4 Mhz

As I understand it, this means the output is at 650 ksps (325 * 2) at 16 bits per sample (10.4 MHz / 650 kHz). This is much higher than your typical application of I2S for audio, which is typically around 48000 samples/sec. This is much higher because it's carrying a baseband RF signal, not just audio.

How might I be able to process this and run it over USB (or just capturing it in general)? Can I even find anything capable of processing I2S at such a high sample rate? Thanks!

Comment: FPGA territory. An FPGA can easily handle that up the point of the USB. There's no half-measures there if you want to stream the data to your PC. You're going to need native USB which means you're going to need IP cores for the USB or an FPGA with a hard CPU with USB capability. And drivers.

Comment: Esp32 should be able to handle the I2S in hardware and stream the data over WiFi.

Comment: @Kartman aaaah, at these rates? Don't think so!

Comment: Roman, on http://www.ham-radio.com/k6sti/xdr-f1hd.htm there's a block diagram, lifted from US patent 7,110,549. My question: are we talking baseband, as in "I/Q" after block 15, or are we talking baseband as in "old-school word for output of FM/AM/… demodulator, containing the audio of interest", i.e., block 16, or are we talking "audio signal", i.e., block 21?

Comment: @marcus muller have a read of the datasheet. The esp32 i2s peripheral will output vga. The 10MHz bit rate is not a problem.

Comment: @Kartman outputting I2S to generate a very forgiving analog waveform is a very different shoe than processing the data rate you're being exposed to and forwarding it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the response. Yep, I'm talking about I/Q after block 15. The pins that I am reading from can be seen in the service manual (https://www.wtfda.org/mem/xdr-f1hd-SERVICE.pdf, pg 14) in cell G2 labelled as "SD_IBOC_OUT_Q", "SD_IBOC_OUT_I", "BCK_IBOC_OUT" and "WS_IBOC_OUT". These pins are normally connected to a different module for decoding digital "HD Radio" which sits IBOC.

Comment: hah! nice manual! That's an interesting device, indeed. It's a bit surprising to find a word select clock on an IQ-carrying digital bus, but this is serial, so it kind of make sense! Luckily that means we don't really have to worry about strange multichannel things. I'd agree with @DKNguyen that this sounds like a job for an FPGA, but maybe this is really benign enough that you can just use something programmable like the cypress FX2 to capture your signal and make it available on high-speed USB. It's been a while since I've played with these (a device I (used to) support uses them) ,

Comment: @MarcusMüller If it's not continuous streaming it makes things a lot easier since you can buffer it all and then send it slowly to the PC through a USB-UART bridge.

Comment: but in general "take in bits serially and latch on an edge of this signal" might be within what can be taught to these rather cheap devices. If you want to see whether it works on a physical level you could buy one of these cheap "USB FX2 logic analyzer eval boards" off amazon or somewhere, and capture the word select.

Comment: @DKNguyen easier, yes, but not really necessary: SDRs, especially the USRP 1 / B100 do pretty much that, with a 10 MHz *parallel* bus, so that should not be harder than one that is 10 MHz serial :) [Link to firmware for FX2 of said device](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/tree/master/firmware/fx2).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the responses. Do you have any suggestions on what I should purchase for this task? Would a microprocessor perhaps exist that could deal with such a high speed I2S interface? At this point I'd be happy just being able to record off the interface, not necessarily even using USB. Thanks again, and apologies for my ignorance. I'm a software guy, not a hardware guy haha.

Comment: I already gave a recommendation: Look into the cypress fx2, these are cheap, you get 10€ evalboards for them on amazon, and I've linked a firmware you could refer to :)