# Capturing High Speed I2S To SD Card

Tags: audio, adc, sd, i2s

I've been working on a project that involves receiving two high speed I2S lines and writing the data off of them to an SD card. The interface has the word select and bit clock I2S lines shared between two seperate data lines, each carrying a mono channel. The word select line runs at 325 kHz, while the bit clock runs at 10.4 MHz. Since each data line is carrying a single mono channel, this means that each line is sending 650,000 samples a second at 16 bits/sample. This means that the entire bitstream I'd like to record onto an SD card is 20.8 megabits/second (ws * 2 * bits/sample * channels). It's also worth noting that this needs to be the "slave" I2S device, as the hardware will need to receive the bit clock externally and not generate its own.

My question is what hardware I should be using to accomplish this task of writing the bitstream to an SD card? My original plan was to use an ESP32 microprocessor to write to an SD card, but in practice I'm having trouble with that. First of all, I can't get the ESP32 to write anywhere near fast enough to the SD card. The maximum speed I could get the ESP32 to write to an SD card using 4-bit SDMMC was 352 KB/s, which is nowhere near fast enough to write this data. Even if I could get the speed I needed, I don't think I could get the two I2S data lines synchronized to each other like they need to be.

Additionally, [I asked a similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614009/capturing-high-sample-rate-i2s-via-usb) before whilst I was trying to send the data over USB instead. I was recommended to try using a cypress fx2 USB microprocessor, but after buying one I realized that I2S doesn't really seem feasible on it. I couldn't find any examples of anyone doing I2S on it, and I can't seem to get anything like it working at all.

What should I try using to write this bitstream to an SD card? Perhaps an FPGA? I've never used an FPGA before, so I wouldn't even know where to start.

Thanks, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The synchronisation of the I2S data should be intrinsic - you grab both channels of data each clock. As for the sdcard write speed, what sort of sdcard were you using? They're not all the same. Assuming the ESP32 code is doing things as fast as the card can cope, then a FPGA (or anything else) is unlikely to do any better. As well, for speed you should bypass the filesystem and write raw sectors - this should give a more consistent write speed. Use a good quality Class 10 card with published specs. Did you try WiFi? What data rate could you achieve with that?

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for the reply. What I meant about syncing the two data lines is that the ESP32 has two I2S separate transceivers. If I start both up one after the other in software, the first one might receive a sample before the other and it will then proceed to lag behind the other. Perhaps I'm worrying about that too much.

Comment: @Kartman Sorry about sending two replies. I thought hitting enter would add a new line, not immediately send the comment. I've tried using different SD cards and they all seem to perform on the ESP32 the same. Meanwhile, I can easily reach 50 MB/s writing to the same cards from my computer. I had also tried using Wi-Fi and sending data via a UDP socket to my computer, but I was still dropping a lot of samples and it couldn't keep up. I didn't do a benchmark on it to see the real data rate, but it was writing samples substantially lower than it needed to be.

Comment: run the ESP32 I2S in two bit parallel mode. The peripheral can go up to 24 bits??(check the datasheet) in parallel mode. There's also DMA to get it into memory without software intervention. Note that whatever platform you use, there is the common issue of the 'sink' device being able to consume the data fast enough. The usual technique is to have a FIFO and size this accordingly, but the FIFO has to be large enough to cope. On your PC you have megabytes of ram, so that makes the issue somewhat easier.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for the response. You are right, increasing the block size to write to the SD card did increase the speeds but they are still not where they need to be. I could reach 90% of the required data rate in the most simple test which was writing empty 65536 byte buffers over and over as fast as possible. Should I give up on trying to make the ESP32 work for my needs?

Comment: you don't give me any hard numbers to guide you either way. What can the sdcard technically achieve vs what you are measuring? It also seems like you're still using the filesystem calls - sdcards don't do 64k blocks. You need to do some detective work and find out where there might be inefficiencies in the sdcard chain. I dare say there's been others that have been down this path and published their results. Also take into consideration peak vs aggregate data rates - the sdcard timing is variable depending on what it has to do internally.